# Inconsistency of capability of random coding in information theory and coding theory

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

In information theory, it is well known that the capacity of a channel can be achieved asymptotically using random coding method (Section 7 of [Cover & Thomas' textbook](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/047174882X)).

However, in coding theory, it is only shown that we can apply random coding method to get a code that achieves Gilbert-Varshamov bound (I will show how this is related to channel capacity and the inconsistence later). To be precise, denote $B_n(r) =| \{ x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n: \text{wt}(x)\le r\}|$ (the size of Hamming ball with radius $r$)

**Theorem**:(G-V bound) There exists a code $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$ such that the distance is $d$ and the size is $|\mathcal{C}|=\frac{2^n}{2B_n(d-1)}$.

This result can be shown by choosing $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{|\mathcal{C}|}$ uniformly and independently. For the proof details, see the [lecture note](https://www.math.toronto.edu/swastik/courses/codes-F22/scribe/lec1.pdf).

Choose $d=2\delta n$ and take the limit $n\to \infty$, we have $B_n(d-1) \approx 2^{nh(2\delta)}$ (see the [asymptotic property of binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas), also page 353 of the [textbook](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/047174882X)). This code can correct $t\approx \delta n$ errors.
Apply this code to a binary symmetric channel with transition probability $\delta$, then we get the message rate $R = \frac{\log |\mathcal{C}|}{n} = 1-h(2\delta)$ with vanishing error probability.

The **inconsistency**: In information theory proof, we use random coding method to achieve the rate $R=1-h(\delta)$ asymptotically with random coding. In G-V bound proof, we only get $R=1-h(2\delta)$ with the same random coding method.

Why is there such a gap on the capability of random coding? Is it possible to use random coding to construct a code with distance $d$ and rate $R \approx 1- h(\frac{d}{2n})$? If yes, does that mean we can get an improved version of G-V bound (in $n \to \infty$ limit) with the same random coding?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think I get your point. The errors cause by BSC noise is almost uniform while the error correcting code needs to handle all extreme errors. Then it seems that, when $n$ is large, we do not actually need a code that can correct arbitrary $t$ errors, and correcting those error that appears with high probability is enough. When we say that LDPC code or polar code achieves the capacity, it should be interpreted in the latter sense. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The GV bound is a lower bound on the capacity, so there is no inconsistency. It just means the GV bound is not tight.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! There is no doubt that G-V bound cannot achieve capacity. What I emphasize here is the capability of random coding method. Or in other words, why can't we use random coding to get a code with rate $1-h(t/n)$ ($t$ is the error number that can be corrected) like the code we get in the proof of channel capacity.

Comment: You can, as you say so yourself in the original question. Are you asking why the GV bound is useful, given it is weaker than what you get by random coding? I think it is because the GV bound makes the dependence on n explicit, and can be better for small n.

Comment: Yes, it’s close. Does that mean we can get an improved version of G-V bound (with explicit dependence of $d$ on $n$) using the same random coding method? This looks natural:  because the code constructed in information theory proof can correct $t\approx \delta n$ errors, then most of the codewords should have distance $2t+1$. (I’m not sure about this, the decoding principle of information theory proof follows the tricky joint typicality)

Comment: @JiaweiWu The recent paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.01403.pdf claims a non-asymptotic improvement using spectral graph theory, FYI. Didn't read in detail.